# Lazy load images in grid view decoding the image path from SD card

Tags: android, performance, android-imageview

Hi i have a set of paths for the images on the SD card, all the images are large like 1024*768 px.

I need to display all these images in a grid view with relatively scaled down images. and i need to first display the grid view and then load scaled down images one generated. How can i achieve this.

Here am now:

getting all image paths,

```
File imgFile = new File(pathToImageOnSD);
            if (imgFile.exists()) {

                BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                op.inSampleSize = 4;

                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

                item.bitmap = myBitmap;
                imageview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            }
```

am doing this for each image path, and i ended with memory error. There are libraries to load images from url but i need a similar one for loading local images on SD card.

Edit:

```
public Bitmap loadBitmapFromPath(File f) {
            // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption

            try {
                // decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
                stream1.close();

                // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
                int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
                int scale = 1;
                while (true) {
                    if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                        break;
                    width_tmp /= 2;
                    height_tmp /= 2;
                    scale *= 2;
                }

                if (scale >= 2) {
                    scale /= 2;
                }

                // decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
                stream2.close();
                return bitmap;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I used the above method to scale down the bitmap, it worked perfectly. But my problem is when i scroll the grid the views are redrawn and flow is not smooth, How to cache these bitmaps and how to lazy load them so that i don't need to wait for the views to be populated completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save memory, always decode bitmaps to the sames size that you plan to display them. For this problem, the official documentation is your best friend. Download the BitmapFun project for exactly how to do this properly. https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Hi @krylez thanks fo your reply it fixes a part of my problem.. i have edited the question with the update.

Comment: The BitmapFun project answers all of your questions. It demonstrates how to fetch the images asynchronously and how to cache them efficiently. Take some time to read through it and really understand it.

Comment: Yes you are right, the sample has every thing but i just need the part which makes my job and am not able to understand some things, it would be better if you could explain me which classes from the sample i can use. Thanks in advance and your answer is accepted